# https:// is not displaying properly on chrome and firefox

Tags: php, wordpress, https

I am new to wordpress website development technology. I have created my website http://www.jhamobi.com. For this website I am using pagelines theme (http://wordpress.org/themes/pagelines). So far so good. But when I am opening https://www.jhamobi.com (secure website) , I am getting display error. Though, http://www.jhamobi.com is displaying properly. I am getting this error on chrome and firefox. It is coming properly on safari. Let me guide where I am going wrong. I have cleared cache on chrome. Do I need to change theme? Do I need any wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is occurring because you are including non-secure files on a secure page. Looking at Firefox's Error Console, you can see a list of the files that are being blocked.

```
Timestamp: 9/13/2013 6:01:10 PM
Error: Blocked loading mixed active content "http://www.jhamobi.com/wp-content/uploads/pagelines/compiled-css-1379114912.css"
Source File: https://www.jhamobi.com/
Line: 0
```

It looks like compiled-css-1379114912.css is the file associate with the layout styles and that's why the site is showing up all over the place. **To fix this issue** just remove all protocol/domain information and leave only the absolute path:

**Example:**

Instead of 
*'http://www.jhamobi.com/wp-content/uploads/pagelines/compiled-css-1379114912.css'*

Use

*'/wp-content/uploads/pagelines/compiled-css-1379114912.css'*

* This will be done in the templates header file (for css and some js) and the footer for the js. The file name will probably look something like `/compiled-css-".time().".css`

Comment: user1056677, Thanks for your guidance. Hope your solution would work for me. But I am not able to understand what are you pointing to? I found compiled-css-1379114912.css and compiled-css-1379123208.css in wordpress -> cpanel -> File manager. I found Unable to get compiled-css-1379114912.css. Hope I am going in right direction.

Comment: Meanwhile , I installed WordPress HTTPS plugin and activate. It resolved my issue. I didn't understand the logic behind it but it worked for me.

Comment: The 1379123208/1379114912 are are timestamps (unix). You need to edit the template's header file before it is rendered. It should reside in /wp-content/themes/(your theme name)/header.php (or similar, the header name can really be anything).